# Business API versioning in JAVA Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest, versioning

What is the best way to do business methods versioning in Spring boot applications. Below is my requirement in simple explanation:

I have one git build with version 1.1.0 having a method

```
public void print hello(){
  System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

After a month, implementation is changed to git build version 1.1.1

```
public void print hello(){
      System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

I can have multiple such git builds and changes may be applied at multiple business logic classes.

I want to do the versioning based on git repository build version.

One way is to have different environment for each deployment but that is not a feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the new functionality gets packaged under a new dir labelled `v1.1.1/`. If its a rest call `.../1.1.1/...` becomes part of the URI.